# syntax error in utilizing between

Tags: mysql, syntax, between

When executing the following code...

```
SELECT city,
6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(RADIANS(40.85093330 - ABS(sample_locations.latitude))), 2) + COS(RADIANS(40.85093330)) * COS(RADIANS(ABS(sample_locations.latitude))) * POWER(SIN(RADIANS(-73.97013820 - sample_locations.longitude)), 2))) AS distance
FROM sample_locations
WHERE sample_locations.latitude BETWEEN (40.85093330 – 10 / (111.04)) AND (40.85093330 + 10 / (111.04)) AND sample_locations.longitude BETWEEN (-73.97013820 – 10 / ABS(COS(RADIANS(40.85093330)) * 111.04)) AND (-73.97013820 + 10 / ABS(COS(RADIANS(40.85093330)) * 111.04))
HAVING distance < 10
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10;
```

I get the error...

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '– 10 / (111.04)) AND (40.85093330 + 10 / (111.04)) AND sample_locations.longit' at line 4 (line 4 is where the first between starts)

Comment: Why do you have `HAVING` clause without any aggregation?

Comment: that won't be the issue as i ran the statement without the WHERE clause and it executed successfully.

Comment: `–` character seems not to be interpreted as a `-` (subtraction sign), change it.